# How to use interceptors in grails 2?

Tags: grails

I'm trying use a filter or an interceptor in Grails 2.5.6. However, it's not executing either.

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action: this.&auth, except: 'login']

private auth() {
    println('test')

}
```

Comment: From what you've provided, this should work.  How are you accessing your controller actions?

Comment: I'm using a URL.  ./<controller>/<action>?<params> It keeps redirecting to the login page.